# MoCap data files applied to avatars using Mecanim

Tags: animation, unity, motion-capture

I am applying some animations (e.g. running) from this free MoCap package that I got off the Unity Assets Store, and as far as I can see from running the animation previews, they seem fine (i.e. playing smoothly) but once I apply them to my avatar (generated through the free AutoDeskCharacterGenerator) and I run the animation, the avatar seems to rise on the floor...

Please see the attached images that illustrate the character (with its collider, etc...) initially being perfectly aligned (touching the ground) but then a few seconds into running, it has been lifted off the ground.

At first, I thought this must be due to the recorded motion data files, but (1) it has happened in every animation I have tried from the package so far, and (2) these motion data files were recorded off real people, so I find it unlikely that all the performers happened to be moving around on very uneven surfaces and slopes.

Has anybody come across this problem before?

[image]

[image]